# Cannot connect Hibernate project with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

[Details about the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DITct.png)I am new to hibernate.I was created a hibernate project.but it cannot connect to the MySQL database.I use SQL workbench as the database and XAMPP server for the SQL server.Please help me to pass the data to mysql database via the hibernate project.

Error message:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Error description:

> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.candidjava.springmvc.controller" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource111" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource111" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.candidjava.springmvc.entity.Employee</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.candidjava.springmvc.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl" />

<bean id="employeeService" class="com.candidjava.springmvc.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl" />
```

database.properties

```
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
database.user=root
database.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Comment: Are you sure that the database is running? Could you put here additional info like your configuration classes with the information about the database connection?

Comment: I edited my question by adding the details about the database and dispatcher-servlet.xml file within my question.Please have a look.

Comment: Please add database.properties as well

Comment: Added.Please have a look.

Comment: Should the database connector version is higher than the MySQL workbench version?